# Can I use 'force-cli import' as a destructive act, to purge unwanted files?

Tags: apex, force-cli

A month ago I started work on a project, building custom Apex classes. For awhile, the project was small, and I could manage it via the Developer Console. That is, by copying-and-pasting my code from my text editor to the webforms in the Developer Console.

Now the project is getting bigger, and I can no longer keep track of things via the Developer Console. I am hoping to use Force-CLI to manage things from this point forward.

When I search Google for info about Force-CLI, there is a lot of information about "export" but very little about "import".

When I run this:

```
force export
```

I get a huge number files, including all of my custom classes. This is great.

Now I have made some changes to the files, and I'd like to send them back to Salesforce. I assume I can do:

```
force import -directory=metadata -c -r -v
```

and this should be fine.

I am curious though, if I have changed the name of files, does "force import" cause the old files to be deleted? I would prefer that, if possible, but I don't see that option. I would like an option that basically empowered me to say "If you don't see a file in my metadata directory, then please erase it from the project."

Is that possible?

And will "force import" generate the XML files for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt, go to the source - [import.go](https://github.com/heroku/force/blob/master/import.go).

As it stands now this command won't be smart enough to diff what you have locally with what is currently in Salesforce a perform the required destructive changes. It is going to do a standard [Metadata API deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) call.

I think the best it can do is the `-autoupdatepackage, -u` option to:

> Auto add files to the package if missing

Keep an eye of [Salesforce DX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforcedx) for changes that will be happening in the future. Some of the developer tooling improvements with the new CLI will be closer to what you want to do.

---

There are a number of [Salesforce IDE's](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/salesforce/4095/tools-for-development#t=201611010117190396205) that could also streamline your deployment process.

In the shameless self promotion category, my employer makes the free [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/09/fuseit-sfdc-explorer-33162747.html) tool. From v3.3 onwards in includes some tools for doing Metadata API deployments. It can monitor a directory for changes and autobuild the package.xml as you work on files. It doesn't do destructive changes automatically for you yet.

Something like [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) would give you much richer functionality for doing deployments.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't get 'force import' to work for me, but I'll ask about that in a separate question.